# "System.IO.File" does not contain a definition for "ReadLines"

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Here I have a csv file of data, 8 strings every line. I need to read it out from csv and display it on screen through a ListView controls.
I created a `List<string[]>` for data adding to `ListView` control. And I need to read data from csv into List. The system I used is a industrial HMI, which use WinCE OS, and vendor claims that it support .NET Compact Framework totally.
The problem I encountered is, when I use `File.ReadLines(path)` to read a line form csv file, error occurs when compiling, and the message show "`System.IO.File`" does not contain a definition for "ReadLines"

I also tried `StreamReader`, same problem.

```cs
namespace Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Graphics.Logic;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;

    using System.Collections; 
    using System.IO; 
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class dmScr
    {       
        public List<string> file = new List<string>();
        public List<string[]> inforead = new List<string[]>();
        void fileload_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            string fileName = (CB_filelist.SelectedItem != null) ? 
                GetStorageCard() + CB_filelist.SelectedItem.ToString() :
                "";
            if(fileName != null && fileName != "")
            {
                fileRead(fileName);
            }
            LV_event.Items.Clear();
            inforead.ForEach(x => 
                {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(x);
                LV_event.Items.Add(lvi);
                });
        }
        private void fileRead(string fileName)
        {
            foreach(string[] item in File.ReadLines(fileName))
                inforead.Add(s);
        }

    }
}
```

The industrial HMI vendor is Beijer, would be familiar if you're working in related field.

Comment: `string[] item` should likely be `string item`.

Comment: You might have to use `StreadReader`, `ReadLine`, however that's a complete guess

Comment: @mjwills but it should be 
```c#
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```
and I use string[] item because there're 8 strings every line, and there're 8 items every culumn in ListView control.

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes I tried, but another problem is , StreamReader return chars not string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure CE supports `File.ReadLines` (not completely sure, don't quote me on this)

However `StreamReader` has a method called [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8)

**Example**

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
     while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
     {
         Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering StreamReader.ReadLine returns string or string[]. For the data I read, each item have 8 columns. So every time ReadLine executed, does it read out 8 strings or combine 8 into 1? Because I need to fill these every 8 strings into a ListView control.
Anyway, there should be some method to solve this. And than you very much.

Comment: @sxjice it reads one line at a time, add them to `inforead.Add(`

Comment: ```C#
  private void fileRead(string fileName)
  {
   using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
   {
    while(sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
     inforead.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
   }
  }
```
and "Cannot be Converted from string to string[]"

Comment: I assume you want to split by something `inforead.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(','))`

Comment: I've just figured it out, and you post this. Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, where can I get .NET Compact methods references?

Comment: @sxjice i honestly don't know